# Select at least one option in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Situation: I want to create a simple code whereby users must select at least one extension to proceed. Users should select at least 1 or more extension, else an alert message will appear.

Problem: The problem is, if there shall be only 1 extension available for selection, whether it is selected or not, the alert message will appear disallowing the registration to complete.

```
//Select atleast one extension 
 var arrCheckboxes = document.checkForm.elements["product"];
    var checkCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrCheckboxes.length; i++) {
        checkCount += (arrCheckboxes[i].checked) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (checkCount > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Select at least one Extension.");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Looking at it, I don't see the issue.  Did you step through it in the debugger to see where it does something unexpected?

Comment: Try console.log(arrCheckboxes) after variable initialization and check what elements are captured.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/ you can modify it according to your alert thing (if  I got the problem right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a legacy from the very early days of browsers that if there is only one form control with a name of *product*, then:

```
document.checkForm.elements["product"];
```

will return a reference to that control, not a collection which you seem to expect. Such controls do not have a *length* property by default so:

```
arrCheckboxes.length
```

returns *undefined* and

```
i < arrCheckboxes.length
```

is false so the loop is never entered.

To fix that, use *querySelectorAll* which always returns a collection:

```
var arrCheckboxes = document.checkForm.querySelectorAll('[name=product]');
```

Supported in IE 8+ and everywhere else. A simpler version of your code (assuming it's in the body of a function):

```
var arrCheckboxes = document.checkForm.querySelectorAll('[name=product]');

for (var i = 0; i < arrCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    if (arrCheckboxes[i].checked) return true;
}
alert("Select at least one Extension.");
return false;
```

Comment: Thank you so much : DDDD I've just tried it and it fixes my problem! You're awesome!